# Geonode: CommandError: One or more models did not validate syncdb

Tags: django

I've just clone geonode and after doing paver setup i made paver start which gave me the following:

```
KeyError: u"Unknown language code 'am'."
```

To solve that i remove the extra languages code defined on **settings.py**:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('es', 'Español'),
    ('it', 'Italiano'),
    ('fr', 'Français'),
    ('de', 'Deutsch'),
    ('el', 'Ελληνικά'),
    ('id', 'Bahasa Indonesia'),
    ('zh-cn', '中文'),
    ('ja', '日本語'),
    ('fa', 'Persian'),
    ('ar', 'Arabic'),
    ('bn', 'Bengali'),
    ('ne', 'Nepali'),
    ('sq', 'Albanian'),
    ('af', 'Afrikaans'),
    ('sw', 'Swahili'),
    ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
    ('ru', 'Russian'),
    ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
    ('ko', '한국어'),
    ('am', 'Amharic'),
    ('km', 'Khmer'),
    ('pl', 'Polish'),
    ('sv', 'Swedish'),
    ('th', 'Thai'),
    ('uk', 'Ukranian'),
    ('si', 'Sinhala'),
    ('ta', 'Tamil'),
    ('tl', 'Tagalog'),
)

EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'am': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'am',
        'name': 'Amharic',
        'name_local': 'Amharic',
        },
    'tl': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'tl',
        'name': 'Tagalog',
        'name_local': 'tagalog',
        },
    'ta': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'ta',
        'name': 'Tamil',
       'name_local': u'tamil',
       },
    'si': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'si',
        'name': 'Sinhala',
        'name_local': 'sinhala',
        },
}
```

but after that it occurs me a different error:

```
 CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
    dialogos.comment: 'author' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    agon_ratings.rating: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    actstream.follow: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    announcements.announcement: 'creator' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    announcements.dismissal: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    user_messages.thread: 'users' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    user_messages.userthread: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    user_messages.message: 'sender' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    account.account: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    account.signupcode: 'inviter' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    account.signupcoderesult: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    account.emailaddress: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    account.accountdeletion: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    avatar.avatar: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
```

A block of errors. What am i missing? It seems it has to do with model relation, but i've just have clone the geonode it was suppose to work, is there anything that i made wrong?

Comment: to solve this i have to pull 2.0.x branch. It will solve. Please someone with more than 1500 rep can add a tag for 'geonode'

Comment: Use a clean environment to install geonode in.

Comment: I have followed the following links for a fresh installation. Try these links and if you still face problem please inform:

http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/install_and_admin/geonode_install/install_geonode_application.html

http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/devel/devel_env/index.html